# cannot convert error when trying to assign List<T> to List<U> where U is T's interface

Tags: c#, linq

here is code illustration

```
interface IObjectA 
{ 
   int Id { get; }
   string Name { get; } 
}
class ObjectA : IObjectA 
{ 
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; } 
   public ObjectA(int id, string name)
   {
       Id = id;
       Name = name;  
   }
}
```

There are two ways for me to generate `List<IObjectA>` from some other objects

First one is using forloop:

```
IList<IObjectA> list = new List<IObjectA>();
foreach(var item in someList)
{
    list.Add(new ObjectA(item.Id, item.Name)); 
}
```

This works perfectly fine.
Then I tried with `linq`

```
IList<IObjectA> list = someList.Select(c => new ObjectA(c.Id, c.Name)).ToList();
```

The compiler will throw me a error basically saying cannot convert `ObjectA` to `IObjectA`

To make it work, i have to add

```
IList<IObjectA> list = someList.Select(c => new ObjectA(c.Id, c.Name)).Cast<IObjectA>().ToList();
```

Can some one explain why the compile would complain?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just because two types, `A` and `B` exhibit a particular inheritance relationship, that does not mean that `G<A>` and `G<B>` will also exhibit the *same* relationship.

Comment: The `T` in `IList<T>` is not [covariant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), therefore, `IList<IObjectA>` is not assignable from `List<ObjectA>`.

Comment: Think about what should happen if you try to invoke `list.Add(new SomeOtherClassThatImplementsIObjectA())` when `list` is of type `IList<IObjectA>` but actually refers to an object of type `List<ObjectA>` (if the compiler was to allow this).

Comment: Thank you all for the explanation. I figure it out why it is not allowed because of the safety issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the linq expressions result in a `List<ObjectA>`. If you can treat this result as a `List<IObjectA>`, the compiler might let you add hypothetical `OtherObjectA` objects to the list, which would blow up on you if you ever tried to cast back to the original `List<ObjectA>` type, which should be allowed.

To get around this, you can `.Cast()` the elements before calling `.ToList()` to get a list of the correct type:

```
IList<IObjectA> list = someList.Select(c => new ObjectA(c.Id, c.Name)).Cast<IObjectA>().ToList();
```

You could also use the `var` keyword:

```
var list = someList.Select(c => new ObjectA(c.Id, c.Name)).ToList();
```

But this will still result in a `List<ObjectA>` and I suspect you need the `List<IObjectA>` for code further on.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you!